# NSWindow - Right click menu

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, contextmenu, right-click

Is there any way to show a menu when a NSWindow is right-clicked?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Rightclick on a view in the window and you will find a property called "menu". Connect this menu property with the menu which should be shown after a right click.

Comment: In case you see this in your inbox later and wonder how people are upvoting an answer you deleted: I edited your answer to fix the one inaccuracy, and called on fellow Stack Overflow users who follow me on Twitter to cast votes to undelete it. After I and two others cast such votes, your now-correct answer became undeleted.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  `NSWindow` inherits from `NSResponder`, which has handy methods like [`-rightMouseDown:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/rightMouseDown%3a).

**edit**

Actually a better way to do it might be to use a custom `NSView` subclass for the window's `contentView`, and override `-menuForEvent:` (a method on `NSView`) to return your right-click menu with the passed `NSEvent` is a right-click event.

Comment: Ok, that's good. How would I make a NSMenu visible just at the point where the user had right clicked though?

Comment: I'm hopeless at this... Is this right? Where do I go from here? - (void)menuForEvent:(NSEvent *)event, then I put if (event == NSRightMouseDown)

Comment: @magikseb: yep, that looks about right (though the method sure not be `-(void)...` but rather `-(NSMenu *)...`)

Comment: I'm sorry. I just really don't understand this. Do I have to pass in an NSMenu as input? What do I do inside the method? :S

Comment: Don't override either of those methods. Set the view's `menu`, and the view will do the right thing for you. You don't even need to subclass NSView to do that.

Comment: I see a downvote—seems somebody took my comment a little too far. Sorry about that. To be fair, Dave's answer will work, and `menuForEvent:` is the correct solution when you need to customize or choose the menu on demand; all I'm saying is that when you don't, it's easier to simply set the menu in the nib (or at run time if necessary).