# Find NSMenu position which was shown on right click

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsmenuitem, nsmenu

In my app I have three `NSImageView`. When the user right click over the imageview, I am showing a `NSMenu` which two `NSMenuItem`s "Add Photo", "Delete Photo". Since I have three Imageview I need to know which imageview shows the menu. So that I can do my stuff for that imageview only.

So how can I do this? I can't find the position of the NSMenu in the window.

Answer (score 1):

If you know when your contextual (right click) menu appears within your app, you should be able to get at the raw "`NSEvent`" data of it happening.  To detect it happening, you have a few options [(like overriding "`rightMouseDown:`" in your "`NSWindow`" subclass)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5120932/981049).

And within that "`NSEvent`", you can fetch the [`locationInWindow`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSEvent/locationInWindow) (I've linked the Apple documentation for you).  With that info, you can check to see if the mouse down falls within the boundaries of your three image view frames.

And then you'll know which photo to add or delete.

Comment: I have connected the menus with the imageviews in xib. So when I right click over imageview, rightMouseUp function not called. It simply shows the menu. In the areas other than the imageview frame, rightMouseUp function gets called.

Comment: You can also subclass your "`NSImageView`" and override `menuForEvent` (another possibility in that answer I linked to). If you can do this within your image view, then you'll know (e.g. from the title or some other attribute) which image view has got the menu event happening.

Comment: If it is not possible, then I will show the menu in the rightMouseUp event rather than xib by programmatically. I think its better than subclassing ImageView.

Comment: don't be afraid of subclassing... it's very easy to do, once you get the hang of it.